Make Libreoffice not round numbers
I have a CSV file that has a single value: 40.23314545498907.
When I open the CSV file with LibreOffice Calc, the value appears rounded to 40.2331454549891. Here is a screenshot of LibreOffice Calc:

What I have tried: I went to Tools -> LibreOffice Calc -> Calculate. Then I cheked "Limit Decimals for general number format" and "precision as shown". But the program keeps rounding the value.
Here is a screenshot of the settings of my LibreOffice Calc:

My Question: How do I configure LibreOffice Calc so that it does not round numbers? In other words, how do I make LibreOffice Calc display the original number 40.23314545498907 instead of the number 40.2331454549891

I’m voting to close this question because LibreOffice isn't a Unix only application; the same concerns may apply to Windows.  It's an interesting question, but it's not a Unix question

@StephenHarris that doesn't matter; see the help page on what is on-topic here: *Applications packaged in nix distributions (note: being cross-platform does not disqualify)

TL;DR.
You're hitting the accuracy limit of the number format LibreOffice uses internally for display purposes. So, you cannot solve this: for whatever you want to do, libreoffice is the wrong tool. It cannot be configured to circumvent this – that's really at its computational core.
Interlude: how to check whether it's internal representation or display conversion
What seems to be happening is that internally, libreoffice calc uses 64 bit floating point, and you can test that:

set the number format of the first two columns of a new sheet to "Scientific" with 20 digits.
enter =EXP(2, -149) into field A1, which is in the order of the smallest number that 32 bit floats can represent.
Put =A1/2 into A2, and
extend down until you hit 6.91615324097812000000E-304 at row 796 (so, cell A796)
in cell B796, enter =A796
in cell B795, enter =A796 * 2
extend up into the first row
now, cells A1 and B1 contain the same value!
Repeat steps 5.-7., but this time, put =A863 into B863, and  in B862, enter =B863 * 2, before pulling up. Now, A1 and B1 differ. You found out that there's subnormal floating point numbers, and where they happen!

Scroll through the first column: Notice how the last 5 digits are always zero? That's actually incorrect. So, while "the math" is done "correctly" (according to IEEE754 number format, which is somewhat sane) under the hood, the display logic is at fault.
Having verified that internally, 64 bit float is used, but we still only see 15 decimal non-zero digits at most, even when configuring to 20 digits of precision (of which we get 21?) we can conclude that libreoffice's number display routines do not adhere to IEEE754 conversion rules from binary to decimal. (they are, quite frankly, badly broken.)
Perspective
General word of advice: if the precision of a 32-bit floating point number is not enough, then your problem is a hard one, and you very likely should not be using "consumer-grade" spreadsheet software.
Or, really, you are trying to store more precision than you really have; 15 to 16 significant (decimal) digits are really a lot. Whatever experiment yields more than that amount of significant digit might be impressive. Or, you are simply ignoring the fact of nature (really is, not just a turn of words) that every measurement is noisy, and are trying to keep digits around as if they were significant, where you should long have been rounding them.

¹ see https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/calculation_accuracy.html ; in that source, libreoffice says that "just like other spreadsheet software", libreoffice uses IEEE754 floats. Which I find surprising – "proper" financial software uses binary coded decimal floating point to be legally compliant. That wouldn't help you here – even that has precision limits (it can store the same amount of numbers with the same number of bits; these are just different numbers).

note that the rounding errors we see here are not to be explained fully by the documentation, but that's not too surprising, there's been some non-standard rounding weirdness in openoffice for as long as I can think. It's really just the wrong tool for precision. I'd go as far as even discourage its usage for financial math of the "household" level (not the "national debt" level), because of such surprises. You want to read CSV files – OK, even if I actively lobby against using CSV for the exchange of numerical data, exactly because you can't represent most numbers that your computer uses …

… precisely as decimal "text" numbers – that's a very valid problem. The Python csv module makes it very easy to read CSV, and it will use the same rounding as your data source uses. (which by the way, is a very specific way to represent 32 bit float as decimal number, not 64 bit as libreoffice claims, but again, when you're in that precision region, libreoffice has long ceased to be the right tool for the job!)

um, my libreoffice has EXP(-149) for e^-149, and POWER(2, -149) for 2^-149. With the latter, I think there shouldn't be any issues with subnormals, since they're all just powers of 2, i.e. with exactly one bit set (until it drops to zero)

honestly, I wouldn't have an issue using LO, or Excel, or any other tool using 64-bit floats, as I don't have nearly enough money for the limited precision of the 53-bit mantissa to matter...

@ilkkachu try it out! the largest normal fp64 is ~ 1e-304, and it goes lower :)

@ilkkachu the reason you don't want binary float in your spreadsheet is not because you need the dynamic range, but because someone could adversely use the rounding rules in a biased way :) it's not about the bits, but about the fact that 1/100 of a € is not precisely representable with no matter how you have of them

I mean, I'm not sure what you mean to try, since you wrote =EXP(2, -149) and my LO doesn't accept that (and neither does Excel, FWIW). But I don't know if that's just some weird version difference or whatever, which is why I'm wondering if you meant 2^-149 or e^-149.

my Libreoffice definitely accepts that. However, formulas in LO calc are localized (really!), so here, try this flat OpenDocument Spreadsheet https://gist.github.com/marcusmueller/38284dccf3bf7d98b444c6c1bf2526ed

(I definitely meant 2⁻¹⁴⁹)

Hmm, if you look at that file, what you have there is EXP(2 -149), without a separator. It has table:formula="of:=EXP(2 -149)" office:value-type="float" office:value="1.44115655096409E-064" and that value matches what other tools give for e^-147. LO didn't agree to change the language for me immediately, but I got Excel to speak German, and it looks to have EXP(x) for e^x and POTENZ(b, y) for b^y. Ah, maybe LO has the same: https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Calc_Functions/POWER/de .

I know from before that Excel localizes things, including the decimal separator, to ahh, "interesting" effects. I don't think I've ever used LO in anything but English, though. Anyway, I did try the experiment you suggested. With powers of 2, I get 2.2250738585072E-308 at 2^-1022, which according to Wikipedia should be the smallest normal number, and then 52 halvings later, the smallest subnormal which LO shows as 5E-324. And it climbs back to the original from those with consecutive doublings. (Excel shows the subnormals as zeroes.) Using a non-power-of two would lose precision of course.

regarding the actual question they asked, it looks to me 40.23314545498907 gives something like 40.23314545498907080 when converted to and back from a double, and I think the next higher number is something like 40.2331454549890779049, so it doesn't look exactly like it would be problem of the actual precision. Just that LO seems to refuse to display more than 13 digits after the decimal point (at least in this case). If you give it that 40.23314545498907  and start adding 0.00000000000001 on top, it eventually shows 40.2331454549892

@ilkkachu exactly! But IEEE754 does define exactly the decimal number that a binary float64 represents. Sure, rounding for display is valid, but if your set your display precision to 20 digits, and it rounds in the first 13 of 14 digits, and fills the rest with zeros, then that conversion-to-decimal algorithm is broken. Even moreso, if the rounding is incorrect.

yes... I just have a hard time seeing how that experiment in the middle of this answer shows... well, anything, really. Since it doesn't seem to work. I think this answer would be better without that distraction.

@ilkkachu hm. It demonstrates that this isn't an internal representation problem, but a fundamentally broken conversion to decimal problem

Which becomes a problem as soon as someone copies a cell "by value" instead of = reference, saves the file and re-opens it, now that I think about it: numerical values are unwisely saved as incorrectly rounded entries in an XML document. Do I wade through decades of OpenOffice/LibreOffice bug tracker?

Somewhat interestingly, =40.2331454549891 - NUMBERVALUE("40.23314545498907", ".") gives me a zero. So I guess it turns it into ...891 internally too? That would mean it doesn't even use the full double precision?? Idk. (Just entering that ...8907 as a number turns it immediately into ...891.) Anyway, I wonder if you missed this or ignored it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/783395/make-libreoffice-not-round-numbers/783396?noredirect=1#comment1500469_783396

ah sorry, didn't mean to ignore it, but had to run around and forgot about it; you're right, that's incorrect, my bad! Having a hard time reconstructing what I did there yesterday
